# order a character array such that all the vowels appear at the last

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

i'm trying to write a program in which a word as a string is provided as an input and i have to rearrange the word such that it just changes the order of the letters in a word by moving
all the vowels to the end, keeping them in the same order as they appeared in the original word

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "application";
            char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
            char x = new char { };
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.Length; j++)
            {
                if ((letters[j] == 'a') | (letters[j] == 'e' ) | (letters[j] == 'i' ) | (letters[j] == 'o' ) | (letters[j] 

== 'u'))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        x = letters[i];
                        letters[i] = letters[i + 1];
                        letters[i + 1] = x;
                    }
                }
            }
            string s = new string(letters);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

the output of the program is

```
ationaplic
```

but the intended output of program is

```
pplctnaiaio
```

Why is my code not producing my intended output?

The edited working code is

```
namespace VowelSort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string word = "application";
            char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
            char x = new char { };
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < letters.Length - count; j++)
            {
                if ((letters[j] == 'a') | (letters[j] == 'e') | (letters[j] == 'i') | (letters[j] == 'o') | (letters[j] == 'u') | (letters[j] == 'A') | (letters[j] == 'E') | (letters[j] == 'I') | (letters[j] == 'O') | (letters[j] == 'U'))
                {
                    for (int i = j; i < letters.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        x = letters[i];
                        letters[i] = letters[i + 1];
                        letters[i + 1] = x;

                    }
                    count++;
                    j--;
                }

            }
            string s = new string(letters);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is `ationapplic` on my computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems I found here:

1. When you find a vowel, you start your inner loop at `0` so you always move the *first* character to the end. Start it at `j` instead.
2. After you've moved a vowel, you start your outer loop at the next letter - so if you have two vowels in a row, you skip the second one (because it's been moved behind he "current" position"). After you're done moving a vowel, decrement `j`.
3. You run your outer loop right to the end, but you should stop it when you get to the vowels you've already moved. Keep count of the number of vowels you've moved, and stop your outer loop when you get to that many characters from the end.

Try to implement these changes yourself, but if you get stuck I can give you some pointers.

Once you have this working, you might like to speed up your inner loop by realising you don't have to perform multiple pairwise swaps - you can just note the vowel you've found, move everything after it up one character, and then insert the vowel at the end.

Comment: +1. You explain why the code of the OP does not work which is, I think, better than giving ready to use code.

Comment: i mistakenly put the wrong code in the question i apologize for that

Comment: @MustansirSabir, the code in your original question was much closer to being correct. The current code will only move the first vowel to the end of the string.

Comment: as you suggested i followed you 1st and 2nd point but the output window doesnot display anything now
if ((letters[j] == 'a') | (letters[j] == 'e') | (letters[j] == 'i') | (letters[j] == 'o') | (letters[j] == 'u'))
                {
                    for (int i = j; i < letters.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        x = letters[i];
                        letters[i] = letters[i + 1];
                        letters[i + 1] = x;

                    }
                    count++;
                    j--;
                }

Comment: That looks pretty good; have you changed your outer `for`-loop to end on `j < letters.Length - count` too? If so, this should now work for you. (If you haven't, you end up repeatedly moving a vowel and decrementing `j` so the loop will never terminate and you'll never get your output printed - maybe this is what you're seeing at the moment.)

Comment: yes i did that but can't display it here as it won't allow me

Comment: @MustansirSabir Try editing your updated code as an addition to your question (don't overwrite the original) so we can take a look for you.

Comment: @Rawling thank you the code is working, it was my system's some kind of temporary glitch,  i'm updating the working code

Answer (score 3):

Having

```
static char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

use this LINQ query:

```
string s = "absdiuoc";
string result = string.Concat(s.ToCharArray()
                                .GroupBy(c => vowels.Contains(c))
                                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                                .SelectMany(g => g));
```

Comment: I was just apout to post an almost identical solution. Anyway here's a live example using this code: http://rextester.com/TGAZ20052 and it does give the OP's required result.

Comment: Oh, 1 point though - `y` is not generally considered a vowel in English.

Comment: When the asker's posted some code that is very close to working, it's a bit harsh to propose a completely different solution.

Comment: I agree with Rawling. This solution, whilst cleaner and more concise will not do much to help OP's understanding of the problems with their code.

Comment: that code is working pretty well but i want to do it using for and if loops

Comment: For the record I totally disagree with the comments above. If the OP is doing something in an overly compex way I think providing a cleaner, neater solution is a more-than-valid answer. It will help future visitors more, and it helps the OP More. IMO

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple LINQ query:

```
word = String.Concat(word.OrderBy(c => "aeiou".Contains(c)));
```

Comment: Nice trick. Never realized bool are also valid for ordering parameter

Answer (score 1):

When your code identifies a vowel, it moves it to the end of the array (thus moving all the letters one space to the left). However your outer loop is still moving on to the next character which means you will miss a vowel if there are successive vowels:

For example, consider the word 'air'. When the variable `i` is at 0, the 'a' is moved to the end:

```
air
^ i=0
```

`i` gets incremented to 1 missing the 'i' now at index zero:

```
ira
 ^ i=1
```

(You will also need to ensure your outer loop stops before it gets to the vowels that have been moved already.)